# Searching HTML img title attributes

Tags: javascript, html, search, dom

Basically I have a html page with hundreds of images on it each with a title attribute describing the image. Ideally I would change all this but the page has to stay as it is for now.

**I want to search these title attributes and scroll the page to the corresponding image** if possible. - I've played around with some javascript search scripts but cannot get it to work with straightforward "On page" searches as the tags are in the code rather than displayed on page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do something like this?

This was the "Search on page" code I was using

```
var n = 0;
function findInPage(str) {
    var txt, i, found;
    if (str == "") {
        return false; 
    }
    // Find next occurance of the given string on the page, wrap around to the
    // start of the page if necessary.
    if (window.find) {
        // Look for match starting at the current point. If not found, rewind
        // back to the first match.
        if (!window.find(str)) {
            while (window.find(str, false, true)) {
                n++;
            }
        } else {
            n++;
        }
        // If not found in either direction, give message.
        if (n == 0) {
            alert("Not found.");
        }
    } else if (window.document.body.createTextRange) {
        txt = window.document.body.createTextRange();
        // Find the nth match from the top of the page.
        found = true;
        i = 0;
        while (found === true && i <= n) {
            found = txt.findText(str);
            if (found) {
                txt.moveStart("character", 1);
                txt.moveEnd("textedit");
            }
            i += 1;
        }
        // If found, mark it and scroll it into view.
        if (found) {
            txt.moveStart("character", -1);
            txt.findText(str);
            txt.select();
            txt.scrollIntoView();
            n++;
        } else {
            // Otherwise, start over at the top of the page and find first match.
            if (n > 0) {
                n = 0;
                findInPage(str);
            }
            // Not found anywhere, give message. else
            alert("Not found.");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is your preferred solution a customized javascript search or the default browser find?

Comment: Javascript search is my prefered soloution

Comment: OT: Use the alt attribute versus title, so that they are accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can select by html attribute.

Using plain JS (in modern browsers incl. IE8+):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[title*="my text"]')
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('[title*=my text]')
```

would find:

```
<img src="/path" title="this is a title with my text" />
```

From there, you would need to get the page position of the image returned by the selector, and then scroll your page to that point, optionally (likely) with some offset so it doesn't bang up against the top of the viewport

**EDIT**:

```
function findElementsByTitle(str) {
    return document.querySelectorAll('[title*="' + str + '"]');     
}

function scrollToElement(el) {
    var yOffset = el.offset().top; //this is a jQuery method...you don't want to write this in plain JS
    window.scrollTo(0, yOffset - 10) //params are x,y. the - 10 is just so your image has some "padding" in the viewport

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'll see how I get on.

Comment: Right I cant seem to implement this within the Javascript search code I've found,can you suggest the simplest way to implement this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Javascript search code"? Can you update your question with what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks for that, should this form call the script correctly?

<form 
name="search" onSubmit="return findElementsByTitle(this.string.value);"> 
<div align="center"> <p><font size=3> <input name="string" 
type="text" size=15 onChange="n = 0;"> </font> <input 
type="submit" value="Search Page"> </p> </div> 
</form>